# Form validation for Empty checking is not working properly In asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation, user-interface

I want to validate my form to avoid Empty. I am using asp.net inbuilt controls on my page i am using loop to check all fields are fill or not but its always showing empty even-though after  filled all field. Is there any another approach to achieve same.

I have design my page in such way that its post back after selection of drop down list. `that's why its not working` i don't know.

```
 <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="DivMainWindow" class="mainHeaderOuter">
        <%--Inside this Div my all ASP controls are present--%>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ddlregion" runat="server" 
          <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
    <dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="deOrderDate" runat="server" Width="220px" AllowUserInput="false" Height="25px"EditFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" DisplayFormatString="dd-MMM-yyyy" EditFormat="Custom"ClientInstanceName="deOrderDate" OnInit="deOrderDate_Init">
    ..............
    <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" OnClientClick="return validate();" runat="server" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" Text="Generate" />

so on
```

JAva script :

```
<script>
  function validate() {
   var inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
   for (i = 0; i < inputTags.length; i++) {
   if (inputTags[i].value === "") {
   alert("All fields are required");
   return false;
     }
    }
  return true;
  }
```

while inspecting on browser i am getting this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
```

I also tried individual control to check its empty or not but its not looping in such a way :

```
var Region = document.getElementById('<%=ddlregion.ClientID %>').value;
var Depot = document.getElementById('<%=ddlDepot.ClientID %>').value;
var INQFileType = document.getElementById('<%=ddlInqfileType.ClientID %>').value;
var QUOFileType = document.getElementById('<%=ddlqoutatfileType.ClientID %>').value;

var elements = document.getElementById("form1").elements;

    for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {

              if (deOrderDate.GetValue() == null) {
                 alert("Please Enter Order Date");
                 return false;
                }
              if (Region == "None Selected" || null) {
                  alert("Please Select Region");
                  return false;
              }

             if (Depot == "Select" || null) {
                 alert("Please Select Depot");
                 return false;
              }

            if (deInqDate.GetValue() == null) {
               alert("Please Enter INQ Date");
               return false;
            }
           if (QUOFileType == "Select") {
               alert("Please Select File Type");
               return false;
            }
          }
       }
```

What i need to change in that to fix this issues

Comment: Does the generated button have a value?  Is the button generated as a `<button></button>` or an `<input type="button">`?

Comment: its <button></button> only i.e. inbuilt asp button control i am using

Comment: `console.log(inputTags[i].outerHTML)` inside the if to see which one it is hitting.

Comment: @Taplar i have added  console.log(inputTags[i].outerHTML)  inside if block but still same thing is happning

Comment: Heh, I know man.  That's not going to change the behavior of the logic.  It **is** going to log to the browser console which one is causing it to think one is blank.

Comment: In my form there are two drop down ares are there both are cascading to each other i check in browser its showing error while selecting drop down list

Comment: You're not listening to what I'm saying.  You are saying your alert is happening.  That means that one of the inputs is recognized as blank.  I don't know which one it is.  You don't know which one it is.  Adding that log statement to your logic will cause your browser to log which one is causing that to happen.  So you can then figure out what the problem is.

Comment: oh okok got it may i create if block for all controllers so that we can easily justify problem

Comment: I am not able to recognize the problem may we suggest me for another method to achieve same

Comment: What element is logged in the console?

Comment: after filling all field i got in console :  <input type="hidden" name="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" id="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" value="">

Comment: So that's the field that is causing your issue.  Is that an input not inside your form?

Comment: so to fix this i need to remove script manager from my page ?

Comment: Or, if that input is not in your form, you need to change your logic to only lookup inputs inside your form.  Because you do not care about inputs outside of your form, right?

Comment: yes no matter its inside or outside

Comment: may you change my logic to only lookup inputs inside your form.?